# Python ML / LSTM Prediction on multiple columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to learn ML, and I have this example which doesn't work as I expect.

Everything works if there is only one column, however, I would like to train model to use multiple columns, for example `open` and `close`. And as soon as I add the second column
`inverse_transform` fails. From what I understood is that there needs to be a special handling of inverse_transform when dealing with 2 column, But I have no idea on how to do that. To reproduce my issue, simply modify this line `features = ["open", "close]`

Down below is a contained sample with dummy values.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import sys, os
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.regularizers import l2


def get_source():
    data = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=(1000, 2))
    data[:, 1] = data[:, 0] + np.random.randint(1, 101, size=1000)
    return [{'open': row[0], 'close': row[1]} for row in data]

def main():
    TRAINING_STEP = 10
    features = ["open"]
    data = get_source()
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=features)
    dataset = df.values

    training_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset) * .8)

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len, :]
    x_train = []
    y_train = []

    for i in range(TRAINING_STEP, len(train_data)):
        x_train.append(train_data[i-TRAINING_STEP:i, :])
        y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

    x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]))

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))


    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1)
    

    # predictin next price from stratch
    data = get_source()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=features)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - TRAINING_STEP:, :]
    x_test = []
    t = len(test_data)
    x_test.append(test_data[t-TRAINING_STEP:t])
    
        
    
    x_test = np.array(x_test)
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], x_test.shape[2]))

    predictions = model.predict(x_test)

    
    result = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
    print("result is",result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

```
scalers = {}
scaled_data = np.zeros_like(dataset)
for i in range(dataset.shape[1]):
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        scaled_data[:, i] = scaler.fit_transform(dataset[:, i].reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
        scalers[i] = scaler
```

Every column must have its own scaler.